Can a space with the following properties exist? Any examples?
Can a space with the following properties exist? Any examples?

The number of geodesic paths between any two points is infinite but countable.

The infimum of the geodesic path lengths between any two points is zero.

For any two points there is a maximum finite geodesic path length.

The maximum geodesic path length between two points has properties, similar to the distance in metric space, except it is, oviously not minimal, but maximal geodesic path.


I want to point out that this hypothetical space has properties, similar to a torus, such as Clifford torus, for example, but with minimum and infimum replaced with miximum and supremum and zero with infinity.
